# Como dar submit em um form sem dar refresh?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Tenho um formulário que é passado para o php via POST.

Como todo formulário, quando é acionado o submit ele dá um refresh
na página, porém meu formulário está dentro de uma modal,
usei javascript para reabrir a modal quando a página atualiza mas mesmo assim gostaria
de submeter o dado sem ter que dar refresh na página.

Estou tentando fazer isso via ajax porém o (formData) que deveria estar
retornando os dados está retornando uma array vazia.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="/home.php" id="form1" class="d-flex flex-row margem-bot-2x">
<fieldset class="border p-2" id="field">  
    <select id="formselect" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
        <option selected>Categoria</option>
        <?php
            $options = "";
            foreach ($data[0] as $value) {
            $options .= "<option value={$value['codigo']}> {$value['nome']}</option> \n";
            }
            print_r($options);
        ?>
    </select>
    <input name="datalist" list="dados" id="formcontrol" class="form-control me-2" placeholder="Digite alguma informação..." aria-label="Search" >
    <datalist id="dados">
        <option><?php if(isset($pessoa)){ print_r($pessoa->nome); }else{ echo "-"; } ?></option>
    </datalist>
</fieldset>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="carregarosdadosaqui()">Pesquisar</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function carregarosdadosaqui(){
var form = document.querySelector('#form1');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // <--- isto pára o envio da form

  var url = this.action; // <--- o url que processa a form
  var formData = new FormData(this); // <--- os dados da form
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  console.log(formData);
  console.log(form);
  ajax.open("POST", url, true);
  ajax.onload = function() {
    if (ajax.status == 200) {
      var res = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText); // a resposta do servidor
      //fazer algo com a resposta do servidor
      alert(res);
    } else {
      alert('Algo falhou...');
    }
  };
  ajax.send(formData);
});
}
```

Comment: Em `console.log(formData)` altere para `console.log(formData.entries())` e veja qual o resultado.

Answer (score -4):

Retire a `action="/home.php"` da tag `<form>`.

O que acontece é que quando você envia o formulário, essa action faz o redirecionamento para o arquivo `home.php`, removendo ele deve resolver seu problema.